# How to convert WSDL file to class file

Tags: wsdl

I have a WSDL file. I want to convert wsdl file to web service class file.

Is it possible? If yes please explain it to me in detail.

Comment: What platform are you using? .NET? Java? Which versions? Are you trying to create classes for a client, or for a service?

Comment: Does anyone has done it without using any third party library, I mean without using any plugin or external jars? If yes, then please share some information regarding that.

Answer (score 15):

1. In Solution Explorer right click on
   your project and go to "Add Service
   Reference..."
2. Press "Advanced..." at the bottom of the window.
3. Press "Add Web Reference..." at the bottom of the window.
4. In the URL field enter the path to the file eg. C:\Documents and Settings\username\Desktop\filename
5. Press Go arrow. Service description should display.
6. Enter the reference name you wish.
7. Press "Add reference".
8. Watch Visual Studio do its magic and making your life easy.
9. Take a break.

Comment: This method is easier if all you have is the WSDL file.

Answer (score 3):

If you are using .NET and you want to create a client class you can use [WSDL.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7h3ystb6(VS.80).aspx).

There are numerous examples on [how to create a Java client proxy](http://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=create+java+proxy+for+SOAP+service+from+WSDL) if you google correctly.

Comment: WSDL.exe is the way to go, especially if your Web service isn't live, and you only have the .wsdl file.

Answer (score 1):

For Android and Iphone: www.wsdl2code.com/
It converts WSDL file to Java and objective c files.
Hopes it help.

Answer (score 0):

A WSDL is more of an interface; it's not going to have any implementation details. If you use WSDL.exe or pull the web service in a project and look at all files, you should get the method signatures.