# Consuming ASMX Web Service With WCF

Tags: wcf, web-services, url, wsdl

I have to write a WCF service that consumes a third party 'Web Service'. They provided WSDL and  the URL so that I can post the transaction. Can some body please help me how to achieve this, with some code example. 
Thanks in advance
BB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this help?

[How to convert WSDL file to class file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2582341/how-to-convert-wsdl-file-to-class-file)

Answer (score 1):

I just used the normal method and they worked fine for me. Just add a web reference to the project and go from there.